# (Rails) Adding new model with initial data to existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've an existing web app that is running in production with user data and various other types of data. I want to add a new model with some initial data for the same.

The data should be there when it goes live. This new data is a one time thing and I don't ever want it to be put back into the database in the future.

I couldn't find an answer to this specific scenario that I have. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *"I don't ever want it to be put back into the database in the future"*? How much data is it?

Comment: Well, I already have a seed file with data that I want to be populated again if this site was set up again in the future, but this new data for this new model should only be put in this one time.

Comment: Do it in a migration.

Comment: Or write a rake task that checks if the table is empty and then populates it with initial data. Another option to writing the migration.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh If I write a rake task, will it only run if I manually run it?

Comment: Yes, only when you run it.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Perfect, that sounds like it'll work.  Thanks!